# How to optimize electron app in memory consuming and package size?

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization, electron

it looks so much. I have just given
npx create-electron-app electron
then direct "npm make" it in my ubuntu, it has created 61MB deb file. and after turn it on, it is taking 101MB from my ram. How can I reduce it?
[image: Screenshot from ubuntu (zorin OS)]

Comment: That's basically the cost of executing an instance of Chrome for your desktop application. Take a look at how much VS code is using: as your app grows, it's going to get worse.

Comment: so there is no way to optimize it?

Comment: No, unless you take on optimising Chrome. But there isn't that much to be done I guess since Google ships it this memory-hungry. (I don't believe that there is anything to "optimise" as this may actually be memory-efficient but just not very lightweight.)

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner My thought is that when an Electron app is only using its own local/private/packaged HTML+CSS+JS and _zero_ externally loaded content from the Internet, then they could run the Chromium engine in single-process mode given the safety-benefits of process-isolation aren't needed at all.